# tabularx vertical line

Tags: tables, color, texmaker, backgrounds

I'm having some problems with the table on latex - texmaker, I would love to have a vertical line for divided c and p thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{graphicx}%tabelle
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

    \caption{}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lYYYY@{}}
        \toprule
    &P
    &
    & C\\
    \cmidrule{1-5}
    &English
    &Original
    &English
    &Original\\
     \cmidrule{1-5}
         & 1- not p
         & 1- non p
                & 1- not c
                &1- non c\\
                & 2- l p 
                &2-l p
                & 2-  c
                & 2- c\\
                & 3- p e
                & 3- a p
                & 3- ce
                & 3- a c\\
                & 4- d p
                & 4- d p
                & 4- d c
                & 4- d c\\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}}
```

If you can also tell me how to name the table I normally able but I avoid in this situation.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Horizontal lines from the booktabs package are designed to be used without vertical lines.

Comment: Why do you declare a total of 5 columns? Your table only seems to need only 4 columns.

Comment: I don't why but I don't like the news ahahah do You have some table format to suggest? I need to make a table at least 10 raws and 7 Columns?

Comment: I used 4 columns but it doesn't work so I use what it work

Answer (score 3):

> I used 4 columns but it doesn't work so I use what it work

The reason why 4 columns don't work is because you start each row with a spurious `&` token -- in effect creating an all-blank first column (which is given type `l`). The solution? Get rid of the spurious `&` tokens.

The following layout may be close to what you're looking to achieve -- well, without the vertical line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Caption Text}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYYY @{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{P} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{C}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
    English & Original & English & Original \\
    \midrule
    1- not p & 1- non p & 1- not c & 1- non c\\
    2- l p & 2- l p & 2- c & 2- c\\ 
    3- p e & 3- a p & 3- ce & 3- a c\\
    4- d p & 4- d p & 4- d c & 4- d c\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want a vertical rule: a space will serve as well, actually better.

I propose three realizations of the table; the first is essentially the same [as Mico's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551089/4427).

I'd consider instead the second one, where the space is more evident; the third one is probably how I'd typeset it, without artificially enlarging the table.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp] % <----- not just h

\caption{Some caption}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{P} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
English & Original & English & Original \\
\midrule
1- not p & 1- non p & 1- not c & 1- non c \\
2- l p   & 2- l p    & 2- c     & 2- c     \\
3- p e   & 3- a p   & 3- ce    & 3- a c   \\
4- d p   & 4- d p   & 4- d c   & 4- d c   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp] % <----- not just h

\caption{Some caption}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{P} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
English & Original & English & Original \\
\midrule
1- not p & 1- non p & 1- not c & 1- non c \\
2- l p   & 2- l p    & 2- c     & 2- c     \\
3- p e   & 3- a p   & 3- ce    & 3- a c   \\
4- d p   & 4- d p   & 4- d c   & 4- d c   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp] % <----- not just h
\centering

\caption{Some caption}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc c cc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{P} &\qquad & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
English & Original && English & Original \\
\midrule
1- not p & 1- non p && 1- not c & 1- non c \\
2- l p   & 2- l p   && 2- c     & 2- c     \\
3- p e   & 3- a p   && 3- ce    & 3- a c   \\
4- d p   & 4- d p   && 4- d c   & 4- d c   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]